# sms is always display "sms sent" even when using random cellphone number without delivery reports - android

Tags: android, sms

Why does whenever I send a sms to a contact number, it always says "SMS sent" when I just used a random cellphone number like "12345678910" which of course has 11 digits. also, it doesn't show the toast when the message is actually delivered or not.

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        
        sentFailed = new ArrayList<String>();

        final String phoneNumberCopy = phoneNumber;
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, uniqueIdPerSMS++,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
            {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
            {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        sentFailed.remove(phoneNumberCopy);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }

        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));  

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

        //send sms
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SMS SENT appeared because you have receiving a sent report from the onRecive method.When your message sent your  Onrecive callback method is called and it fires SMS SENT Message